# Error when attempting to deploy Next.js app to Zeit cloud, running in dev mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, next.js, vercel

I am unable to deploy my Next.js App to Zeit using the `now` command.

I tried uninstalling `sass` reinstalling `npm i node-sass` as well as `npm i node-sass --force`. None of this worked. I get the following error.

```
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node XX.X.X
```

[image]

The application must deploy or at least run in dev mode 'now dev'. It runs fine in my local dev environment when I run 'npm run dev'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I fixed the problem was, I wrote a bash script that does the following steps.

```
# Delete build files

sudo rm -rd .next

# Delete node modules

sudo rm -rd node_modules

# Then I ran this without installing the node_modules again

now dev
```

When I let the zeit builder install the `node_modules` the test deployment worked like a charm.